# Where is Drupal Organic Group Role Data stored? How do I access it?

Tags: drupal-7, organic-groups

I've created a custom Role for my Group. 
I've assigned a user, who was a member of the Group, to this special Role.
Now, I want to access a user's Role in the Group via PHP, but I can't find it anywhere.
I've pored over the Devels of both the User and Group.  I can access the fact that the user is a *member* of the group in the user's group_audience array, but not what their *role* is in that group.

Any advice?

Edit: Drupal 7

Comment: what version of Drupal and OG are you using? 6 or 7?

Comment: OG 7.x-1.x-dev, Drupal 7

Comment: @Dan I've just updated my answer; I think it will now answer your question specifically. I hope you got it sorted, in any event, but please do give me a shiny green tick if I actually answered your question  ;o)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** There's some background here first, then the actual answer is after that.

### Background

Looking in the mySQL database on our development server, there seems to be a handful of OG-related tables in our Drupal database. I'm pretty sure the version running on the devserver is og-7.x-1.x-dev.

- `og`
- `og_membership`
- `og_membership_type`
- `og_menu`
- `og_role`
- `og_role_permission`
- `og_users_roles`
- `field_data_og_membership_request`
- `field_revision_og_membership_request`

Their definitions look like this:

```sql
mysql> describe og;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| gid         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| etid        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| entity_type | varchar(32)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| label       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| state       | int(11)          | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| created     | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> describe og_membership;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| etid        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| entity_type | varchar(32)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| gid         | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| state       | varchar(255)     | YES  |     |         |                |
| created     | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe og_membership_type;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| description | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| status      | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| module      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe og_menu;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| gid       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| menu_name | varchar(128) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe og_role;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| rid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| gid   | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name  | varchar(64)      | NO   |     |         |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe og_role_permission;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| rid        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| permission | varchar(64)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| module     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe og_users_roles;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| rid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| gid   | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe field_data_og_membership_request;
+------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                        | Type             | Null | Key | Default |
+------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+
| entity_type                  | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |
| bundle                       | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |
| deleted                      | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |
| entity_id                    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| revision_id                  | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
| language                     | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |
| delta                        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| og_membership_request_value  | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL    |
| og_membership_request_format | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
+------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe field_revision_og_membership_request;
+------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                        | Type             | Null | Key | Default |
+------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+
| entity_type                  | varchar(128)     | NO   | PRI |         |
| bundle                       | varchar(128)     | NO   | MUL |         |
| deleted                      | tinyint(4)       | NO   | PRI | 0       |
| entity_id                    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| revision_id                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| language                     | varchar(32)      | NO   | PRI |         |
| delta                        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| og_membership_request_value  | longtext         | YES  |     | NULL    |
| og_membership_request_format | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
+------------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(I've removed the empty Extras column from the two `field_*` tables to avoid horizontal scrolling.) Hope that helps?

### My workings

Having just had to mess with this myself on my own Drupal site, it turns out that `og_membership` has a row for each user in each group (I've abbreviated the `type`, which read `og_membership_type_default`):

```sql
mysql> select * from og_membership where gid = 324 and etid = 182905;
+--------+-----------------+--------+-------------+-----+-------+------------+
| id     | type            | etid   | entity_type | gid | state | created    |
+--------+-----------------+--------+-------------+-----+-------+------------+
| 223562 | og_m..._default | 182905 | user        | 324 | 1     | 1329388409 |
+--------+-----------------+--------+-------------+-----+-------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

In this row, the `id` is an autoincrementing identifier for the table `og_membership`, the `etid` corresponds to the `users.uid` for the user in question and `gid` corresponds to to the `og.gid` for the group in question.

So if I run the query

```sql
update og_membership set gid = 38 where gid = 324;
```

then all the members of group #324 are moved to group #38 (which is what I've just needed to do, due to an error in an import script).

I *think* the answer to *your* question is that the `og_membership.type` corresponds to an `og_membership_type.name`. Looking at that table:

```sql
mysql> select * from og_membership_type;
+----+----------------------------+-------------+--------+--------+
| id | name                       | description | status | module |
+----+----------------------------+-------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | og_membership_type_default | Default     |      2 | og     |
+----+----------------------------+-------------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

, I *think* the `og_membership_type.status` corresponds to the `og_role.rid`:

```sql
mysql> select * from og_role;
+-----+-----+----------------------+
| rid | gid | name                 |
+-----+-----+----------------------+
|   1 |   0 | non-member           |
|   2 |   0 | member               |
|   3 |   0 | administrator member |
+-----+-----+----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Actual answer

So I think the query you want is:

```sql
select og_role.name
from og_role
    inner join og_membership_type on og_role.rid = og_membership_type.status
    inner join og_membership on og_membership_type.name = og_membership.type
where og_membership.gid = $group_id;
```

where `$group_id` is the `og.gid` of the group in question. (The ID that appears in the URL is the `og.etid`, so you might want to add another `join` to that query.